# How is the property Tag commonly used for Windows forms checkboxes?

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox

MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.tag.aspx
says it Gets or sets the object that contains data about the control.

How is this commonly used. Can it just contain a string related to the control ? Or does it commonly have an object the control uses ?

Comment: Your questions are all answered in the doc you linked to. In the GUI builder you can only assign a string. It's purpose is to create an associate between an object and the Form that displays that objects data.

Comment: Did you look at the example in the link you posted? It's pretty self-explanatory.

Comment: Thanks. I wanted to know the common purpose of this property and if it is commonly used. I am pretty new to .NET or Winforms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't commonly used.  The Tag property was inherited from the VB6 object model.  Which didn't nearly have as much utilitarian power as the .NET framework or Winforms.  So the Tag property was often used to hang context data off a control.  That it is an Object didn't matter in Visual Basic.

In C# that's less than desirable.  And much easier to separate the data from the view.  And much easier to derive your own control from Checkbox and add your own methods and properties.  But you can still use the Tag property if you want to.

Answer (score 1):

This is purely for your use. The control doesn't do anything with it other than store it for you.

People often put additional information about the control for reference later.